# Stable points in a GIT quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

I have a maybe stupid question on GIT:

Let $\mathbb P^N=\mathbb P^N_k$ be the Hilbert scheme of hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^n$, where $N=\binom{n+d}{d}-1$, and let $G:=PGL_{n+1}(k)$. Then we can consider the action $\rho:G\times \mathbb P^N \to \mathbb P^N$. If $x\in \mathbb P^N$ is a stable point, then by definition the orbit $G.x$ should be closed.

However, this looks very weird to me. Note that $PGL_{n+1}(k)$ is an open set in $\mathbb P^{n^2+2n}$ and $\mathbb P^N$ is proper, by valuative criterion, there is a unique extension "$\mathbb P^{n^2+2n}. x$" of $G.x$, which is just the closure $\overline{G.x}$. Let $x\in \mathbb P^N$ be any stable point. Then $\overline{G.x}-G.x$ really contains some very bad point: since $\mathbb P^{n^2+2n}-PGL_{n+1}(k)$ contains non-invertable linear transformations, $\overline{G.x}-G.x$ contains hypersurfaces defind polynomials with fewer variables, hence is certainly unstable. So, this means $x$ is never stable.

I know this must be wrong but I did not find where is my mistake. I would be appreciated if someone could help.

Comment: How are you using the valuative criterion?

Comment: @Mohan One can take one parameter subgroup $\mathbb G_m$ of $PGL_{n+1}(k)$ and then the valuative criterion says $\mathbb G_m.x$ has limit at zero. Or I think this is also not necessary: let ${\rm diag(1,1,\ldots,\lambda)} \in PGL_{n+1}(k)$ acts on any $x\in \mathbb P^N$. When $\lambda \to 0$, the limit is certainly an unstable point.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the 'unique extension "${\mathbb P}^{n^2+2n}\cdot x$" of $G\cdot x$' must be wrong. For instance, take $G=PGL_2\subset {\mathbb P}^3$ acting on $ {\mathbb P}^1$ in the usual way. Then your argument would give that the map $g\mapsto  g\cdot(1:0)$ must extend, to give a non-constant morphism from ${\mathbb P}^3 \to {\mathbb P}^1$, which cannot exist.... Do you agree?

Comment: @peterag I think the uniqueness should be ok, and the problem might be that, the "extension" part is not algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer to my own question. Indeed, $G.x$ may not be equal to $\overline{G.x}$, even when $x$ is stable. The fact that $G.x$ is closed for $x$ stable only holds in the affine case. See [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiwjqnLwNXiAhVQYlAKHVRQBzUQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.staff.uni-mainz.de%2Fpommeren%2FMathMisc%2FHilbMumf.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1a1_mRdICJKho4gcW6fD-3).